# Why we use different languages in postgresql function

Tags: plpgsql

Create Function Abc()
Returns setof 
as $$
language **'sql'**
or
language **'plpgsql'**

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports more languages long time - originally, there was functions in SQL language. This language is great for simple tasks, can be used as macro - some simple cases are inlined (and then the overhead of wrapping code to function is zero). And anybody knows SQL.

PLpgSQL is based on Oracle's PL/SQL - it is great procedural languages with integrated SQL. Lot of people knows PL/SQL and can quickly works with PL/pgSQL.

PLPerl, PLPerlu, PLPython - these languages are languages for external procedures. These languages are generic - has not optimized for usage inside databases, but can do very fast lot of other tasks or can use pretty wide set of libraries (although this usage can be little bit dangerous) - "u" at end means "untrusted".

Mostly time PostgreSQL developers uses SQL for one line functions (it is like macro languages), and PLpgSQL for manipulation with data. Languages for external procedures are used exceptionally - I like use Python for XML parsing for example.